# finding an index by recursively cutting the array in half

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I want to find an index making the less possible yes/no questions in a x^2 array, for this I assumed a cool approach will be to find the col position by cutting at the half (or near the half) and asking `is col <= half?` depending on the answer, I will pick one of the halves and repeat this until the `length == 1`, then make the same but with `is row <= half?` to find the row.

This is my function (first time attempting a recursive function):

```js
function recursiveFunc(indexPos, currentArrLen, moveIndexBy, countLoops){
    var aproxHalf, relativeIndexPos;

    relativeIndexPos = (indexPos-moveIndexBy);
    aproxHalf = Math.floor(currentArrLen/2);

    if(currentArrLen<2){
        return (moveIndexBy+" "+countLoops);
    }else{
        countLoops++;

        if(relativeIndexPos>=aproxHalf){
            moveIndexBy += aproxHalf;
            currentArrLen -= aproxHalf;
        }else{
            currentArrLen = (aproxHalf-moveIndexBy);
        }

        return recursiveFunc(indexPos, currentArrLen, moveIndexBy, countLoops);
    }
}
```

The only var that seems non self explanatory might be `relativeIndexPos`, so I will explain it, the value of it is the index of the index we are trying to find but within only the smaller array (e.g if we had 5x5 finding index 2, the new array length after cutting it once is 3, the relative index of 2 in that array `[0,1][<2>,3,4]` is 0)

**edit:** okay maybe I should explain `moveIndexBy`, it basically is "the leftest index at the current working array"

It works on a 5x5 array, for example if I give `x` the values of 0 to 4 in `recursiveFunc(x,5,0,0);`, it will correctly find the index in the less possible questions `<index/questions> 0:2, 1:2, 2:2, 3:3, 4:3`.

But this fails with bigger arrays, for example, a 10x10 will give:

```
0 3
1 3
2 3
3 4
4 4
5 2
5 2
7 3
8 4
9 4
```

The 5 and others are wrong, it can't possibly find `5` in 2 steps: `0 1 2 3 4 (5 6 7 8 9)` then `5 6 (7 8 9)` you still need to see if the index is the left or right of `5 (6)`. Also it fails to even find the index `6`

Comment: It's called [binary search](https://www.google.com/search?q=binary+search)

Comment: Where is your function actually accessing an array?

Comment: @Bergi it isn't really accessing the array, the first time it runs I pass the length of one side to `currentArrLen` and the solution on `indexPos`, for now I just want to know how many 'yes/no questions' it asks, I am just comparing the effectiveness vs other methods for now

Comment: Oh, a function that gets passed it result just to see how the computation would have worked out… Maybe you should have explained *that*.

Comment: log2(N) yes/no questions.

Answer (score 0):

`currentArrLen = (aproxHalf-moveIndexBy);`

to

`currentArrLen = aproxHalf;`

I don't know what or why, but that fixed it:

```
0 3 
1 3 
2 3 
3 4 
4 4 
5 3 
6 3 
7 3 
8 4
9 4
```

**edit:** with that, an undocumented bug of length being sometimes 0 is fixed too, so change `if(currentArrLen<2)` to `if(currentArrLen==1)`